# Departure point for research in economics

Tags: scientific-method

I hope this is the place to ask this question. 
I am in the first year of PhD in economics. As most of PhD students in economics, I try to show some economic mechanisms by modelling.

Most of time, I have a tendency to base largely on other models in the literature. I try to incorporate my idea in existing models but it does not work really well. 
For those who are in economics, how do you start to model your idea ? Do you start from a really basic model and complexify after ?

Comment: Why negative votes ? I don't understand the logic ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about economic modelling, not academia. If you can edit it to be more specific, it could be migrated to [economics.se] - flag it for moderator attention after editing it.